# autosave on change event

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have written a script that saves the textarea value automatically onchange event of the textarea. The issue I am facing is when user types something and suddenly stop then the onchange doesn't trigger until the user clicks elsewhere on the screen. Isn't it possible to make my script work in a way that when the user stops typing on textarea:

`<textarea onchange="onautosave()" id="autosave" ></textarea>` lets say for five seconds then the function `onautosave()` gets triggered? Kindly let me now how can I do it. Thanks

Comment: You might use keyup and keydown.. But think about a way to prevent your server from being overrun by save requests ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onkeyup` event and `setTimeout()` to trigger auto save. Here is the code (just to sketch the whole thing)

## HTML

```
<textarea onkeyup="autosave()" id="autosave" ></textarea>
```

## JS

```
var autosave_timer = null;

function save() {
    // actual save code
}

function autosave() {
    if(autosave_timer)
        clearTimeout(autosave_timer);

    autosave_timer = setTimeout(save, 5000);
}
```

Please note cleating timeout. It helps not to overwhelm server.

Comment: If I am not wrong the answered code only works with respect to timer and the timer will only start then when the user stops typing on the textarea?

Comment: The timer will start on first typed character and reset on every next typed character. But essentialy it could be said that the timer starts when the user stops typing.